# How to "unlink" a table line in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, calendar, tabular

I need to change a plugin that build a calendar with events. The problem is that these events (that can have one or two lines) are built in rows, not columns. What causes that the events with TWO LINES fill in the spaces below the next horizontal events with ONE LINE. Generating blank spaces.

Here is an illustration of what I'm talking about:

[image]

What I need to know is if there is a way to "unlink", or "break" the cell connection with the "TR" of the table, so that the cell adjust its height according to its content, not the full height from the "TR".

Sorry if it sounds confusing.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sua780k5/
`link`

EDIT: I'm using a plugin called FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/)

Comment: How did you arrive at that point? Please share your code, preferably on jsFiddle. 
Usually, cells within a TR are the same height. Are you using `rowspan`? How is your HTML generated? You could also use absolute positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585789/css-rowspan-like-effect

Comment: I'm using a plugin called FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/). I've changed the code to support at least 2 lines because the project needed it. As far as I know, any of the plugin versions support double lined events :(

Comment: Could you then supply the outcome at least? HTML and CSS? Or share a link? We can't give answers to unknown problems

Comment: Of course! Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/sua780k5/ Thank you for your attention! Unfortunatelly for me is not an option changing the main core of the plugin to change its structure.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! It doesn't look good, I'm afraid. Without something like using JS to re-build the table going by column-containers, it won't work this way. The next best thing is to have them all be at least 2 lines high :/

Comment: I was thinking about this JS re-build option, for now it's the best option I have haha I will try. Thank you for your time and have a great day!

Comment: Sure :) If it turns out you get stuck and can't find any answers, feel free to come back here :)