# Can I make a td rowspan just by using css?

Tags: css, html-table

I am modifying a website using a Userscript, sorting a table and joining the first column of rows of same type. The result is something like this:

```css
table, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 3px }
.alternate td.image { display: none }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td rowspan="3" class="image">Image 1</td><td>Info 1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class="alternate"><td class="image">Image 1</td><td>Info 1.2</td></tr>
  <tr class="alternate"><td class="image">Image 1</td><td>Info 1.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="2" class="image">Image 2</td><td>Info 2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class="alternate"><td class="image">Image 2</td><td>Info 2.2</td></tr>
</table>
```

So first I add the class `alternate` to rows that aren't the first one, and then I calculate the rowspan. My question is: could I achieve this using only CSS, and make the first column automatically span over all the `alternate` rows below, without having to calculate the rowspan?

Comment: This answer is a bit old, but possibly a duplicate and answer to what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585789/css-rowspan-like-effect

Comment: Your problem is that without the userscript, the only way to distinguish between the Image1 rows and the Image 2 rows is the content, and you can't select elements by their content in CSS.

Comment: I dont mind keeping the script, just dont want to calculate the rowspan @Alohci